# Subnet of a sequence.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, nets

Denote by $I$ the interval $[0,1]$. The space $\{0,1\}^I$ can be viewed as the space of all functions
$$f: I \to \{0,1\}.$$
With the product topology (or equivalently, the point to point convergence topology), $\{0,1\}^I$ is known to be compact but not sequentially compact.

An example of a sequence without convergent subsequence is $f_n$, where $f_n(x)$ is the n-th binary digit of $x$ (where the number of ones cannot be finite, to avoid different binary representations).

Now, there is no subsequence $n_k$ such that $f_{n_k}(x)$ converges for all $x$. Just take an $x$ such that its binary expansion has the $n_k$-th digit equals to $0$ when $k$ is even and $1$ otherwise.

But since $\{0,1\}^I$ is compact, $f_n$ is supposed to have a convergent subnet! I would like to see such a subnet. :-)

Can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't know if you can. Tychonoff's theorem is proven using the axiom of choice, so it's more than likely you will need choice to construct such a subnet which is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: More specifically, the point of convergence must be basically a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$, so requires the existence of a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ (e.g. ultrafilter lemma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick an ultrafilter $F\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N).$ Let $f$ be the function that sends $r$ to $1$ if and only if $\{n\mid f_n(x)=1\}\in F.$ Note $F$ is a directed set under inclusion.

I will argue that the subnet defined by $f'_{S}=f_{\min(S)}$ for $S\in F$ converges to $f.$ Any basic open set containing $f$ is of the form $U=\{g\mid g(r_i)=f'(r_i)\text{ for all $1\leq i\leq k$}\}.$ The sets $\{n\mid f_n(r_i)=f'(r_i)\}$ are in $F,$ so their intersection $S$ is in $F,$ and any $n\in S$ satisfies $f_n\in U.$ So $f'$ is eventually in $U,$ which is the definition of a limit.

Comment: Why is it a subnet?

Comment: @AndréCaldas: the function $S\mapsto \min(S)$ is final (it's non-principal, so doesn't contain $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for any $n,$ so must contain $S\setminus \{1,\dots,n\}$) and monotone ($\min(S\cap T)\geq \min(S)$)

Comment: So, for each ultrafilter, we have a different limit? Nice! We can also use $\{n\,|\, f_n(x) = 0\}$ and send $x$ to $0$, right? And those would be different limits because the number of zeros could be finite, depending on $x$. Very nice! Thank you.